# Is each element of the 2nd array the equivalent of the first array elements squared (CODEWARS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging, compare

I am attempting a 6kyu problem on codewars and have stumbled upon an annoying error that I cannot get to the root of.
Quick explanation of the task : "Given two arrays a and b write a function  comp(a, b) that checks whether the two arrays have the "same" elements, with the same multiplicities. "Same" means, here, that the elements in b are the elements in a squared, regardless of the order.

My code seems to return 1 each time even after playing around with it and I am not sure why, I am not looking for an answer to the question just an explanation of why my code is returning what it is.
Thank you for any help!

```
    function isTrue(el){
  return el === true;
}

function comp(array1, array2){
  var arr = array1.map(function(num){return num*num});
  var arr2 = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(array2.includes(arr[i])){
      return arr2.push(true);
    } else{
      return arr2.push(false);
    }
  }
  return arr2.every(isTrue) ? true : false;
}

comp([121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11],[121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]);
//return value 1, should be true
```

Comment: You're using `return` in your `for` loop. Your function will stop as soon as it hits the first `return` in the code path.

Comment: Very sloppy and basic mistake.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You return the result of [Array#push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) at `arr2.push(true);` or `arr2.push(false);`. The [return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Return_value) of push is

> The new length property of the object upon which the method was called.

Hence, your code returns 1 after doing the first push.